# Edit password : is it a security issue if i tell to user if new and old password match?

Tags: security

I am currently trying to create a edit password page (to change the user password).

I want to tell to the user that if he enters the same password than the old one then I will show an error message which shows that two passwords match and that's useless to change it.

Take a look https://prnt.sc/pe8xur

Is it a security issue if I do that ?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how this could be an issue if it is done client side only

Comment: Just wanted to make sure ! :) thanks